# Swift: XCode6 Beta 5 giving errors on core data objects in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am developing an application in `swift` programming language. I was using the XCode6 Beta4 version and all the things were running smoothly and fine. I have updated the version to Beta5 today and I am getting the errors on core data objects which are:

1. Type '`NSManagedObjectContext`' does not conform to protocol '`BooleanType`'.
2. Type '`NSManagedObjectModel`' does not conform to protocol '`BooleanType`'.
3. Type '`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`' does not conform to protocol '`BooleanType`'.

Screenshot of errors is also attached.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually you are getting the error that `NSManagedObjectContext?`, `NSManagedObjectModel?` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?` do not confirm to `BooleanType` protocol. Notice `?` question mark at the end of the type name.

So you are dealing with Optionals. Since Beta 5 Optionals does not conform to `BooleanType` protocol anymore.

You need to check for `nil` explicitly, change:

```
if !_managedObjectContext {
    // ...
}
```

to:

```
if _managedObjectContext == nil {
    // ...
}
```

And do the same for `_managedObjectModel` and `_persistentStoreCoordinator`.

**From xCode 6 Beta 5 Release Notes:**

> Optionals can now be compared to nil with == and !=, even if the
>   underlying element is not Equatable.

and

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue)
>   protocol, so they may no longer be used in place of boolean
>   expressions (they must be explicitly compared with v != nil). This
>   resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more
>   explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the
>   rest of the language. Note that ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional still
>   includes some BooleanType functionality. This issue will be resolved
>   in a future beta.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if _managedObjectContext == nil` instead of `!if _managedObjectContext` and do the same to `persistentStoreCoordinator` it's because apple changed something with BooleanType (and not just with if) with xCode beta 5 update.